# Можно ли в Java достать сессию, после того как удалили Cookies?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, сессия хранится в Cookies, можно ли в Java достать сессию, после того как удалили Cookies?

Comment: А что вам помешает до удаления Cookies вытащить id сессии и где-нибудь сохранить?

Comment: но если же все таки не сохранил Cookies до удаления их пользователем, можно ли все таки как-то достать сессию?

Comment: Сомневаюсь. Уточните какую библиотеку/класс используйте и пример кода бы :)

Comment: Спасибо, решил сделать как вы сказали ранее, сохранять сессию не в куках.